# open app link in uiwebview not in iTunes

Tags: xcode, uiwebview, itunes

I want to open some app web page in a UiWebView like this link :

`http://itunes.apple.com/app/remote/id284417350?mt=8`

The problem is that the device open automatically iTunes and quit the application. I want just to display the app web page without launching iTunes.

Comment: Do you expect the link to open in your app or in Safari?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

[webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:
                                                   @"Put link here"]]];

webview.scalesPageToFit = YES;

}
```